# Мнение WindowsXP vs. Windows 7

Tags: windows, windows-7, windows-xp

Доброго времени суток. Не исключаю холивар, но, тем не менее, хотелось бы услышать ваше мнение в пользу выбора установки WindowsXP или Windows 7 на рабочий компьютер.

Характеристики:

```
Блок питания: IN-WIN IP-S450HQ7-O 450WМатеринская карта: P8H61-M LE LGA1155Процессор: Intel Core i5-2400 Sandy Bridge (3100MHz, LGA1155, L3 6144Kb)DDR: Kingston KVR1333D3N9K2 2x2 Gb DDR3 1333 МГц
```

Задачи, которые будут выполняться: браузерные флеш-игры, видео-захват, обработка видео.

Comment: Win7 x 64 вполне подойдет!

Comment: Я знаю, что подойдет. Меня интересует вопрос "почему?"

Comment: Windows 7 х64, так как ХР тут совсем плясать не будет...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WIN 7 работает намного стабильнее чем WIN XP, чем WIN VIsta.

Собственно 7ка это улучшенная Vista без глюков и косяков.

Работает быстрее чем XP и Vista. Более дружелюбна и нареканий за 2,5 года не вызывала.

64х пашет на ура.

Собственно ставь 7ку и не парься.

> браузерные флеш-игры, видео-захват,обработка видео.

Вот тут только ты в характеристиках не указал видео, собственно для обработки видях, нужна видео нормальная, оператива и быстрый винт.

Comment: Спасибо. Собственно, именно такой ответ я и ожидал.